# What is the best way to manage a user's session in React?

Tags: session, reactjs

I have a doubt about how to manage a user's session in React, for example in MVC .NET you only just do this using the Session object (e.g. `Session["test"] = "";`), but obviously React can not do this.

I was reading about using the component state, I suppose that sets the state at the principal component and passes this state to other components using props. Also I saw people recommending the use the browser's `localStorage` or cookies, but I don't know if this if a good idea or practice.

Is there a better way to manage sessions variables in React than `localStorage` or cookies?

Comment: Session is executed on server side. React is working on client side so the only option is by using local storage to store temporary information.

Answer (score 51):

I would avoid using component state since this could be difficult to manage and prone to issues that can be difficult to troubleshoot.

You should use either `cookies` or `localStorage` for persisting a user's session data. You can also use a closure as a wrapper around your `cookie` or `localStorage` data.

Here is a simple example of a `UserProfile` closure that will hold the user's name.

```
var UserProfile = (function() {
  var full_name = "";

  var getName = function() {
    return full_name;    // Or pull this from cookie/localStorage
  };

  var setName = function(name) {
    full_name = name;     
    // Also set this in cookie/localStorage
  };

  return {
    getName: getName,
    setName: setName
  }

})();

export default UserProfile;
```

When a user logs in, you can populate this object with user name, email address etc.

```
import UserProfile from './UserProfile';

UserProfile.setName("Some Guy");
```

Then you can get this data from any component in your app when needed.

```
import UserProfile from './UserProfile';

UserProfile.getName();
```

Using a closure will keep data outside of the global namespace, and make it is easily accessible from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Is it a safe procedure?

Comment: It is safe if you are storing user data that is already visible on the web site(e.g. name, email, phone number etc.). I would not use this to store a credit card number for example. ;)

Comment: Just to get my understanding right, this method is not a full implementation for a session, right? It still needs to be persisted somehow.

Comment: Correct. The UserProfile closure could be modified to store the attributes in localStorage as well, if persistence is required

Comment: @ernesto petit: Does this help? This question is getting visibility, so you should accept this answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: Is not the same thing to define some class instead use Clojure syntax? What is the advantage?

Comment: Looks like this code ended up here: https://medium.com/@atif.ali.ati/user-session-in-react-js-aa749bc4faf6

Comment: @mattburns can they just take an answer like that without giving credit? Looks like plagiarism to me.

Comment: @grizzthedj Would you want the closure accessible via Context or Redux or are you suggesting something else?

Answer (score 22):

I created a React module called `react-client-session` that makes storing client side session data very easy. The git repo is [here](https://github.com/grizzthedj/react-session).

This is implemented in a similar way as the closure approach [in my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420531/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-a-users-session-in-react/42421185#42421185), however it also supports persistence using 3 different persistence stores. The default store is memory(not persistent).

1. Cookie
2. localStorage
3. sessionStorage

After installing, just set the desired store type where you mount the root component ...

```
import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session';

ReactSession.setStoreType("localStorage");
```

... and set/get key value pairs from anywhere in your app:

```
import { ReactSession }  from 'react-client-session';

ReactSession.set("username", "Bob");
ReactSession.get("username");  // Returns "Bob"
```

Comment: If you made this, you should clarify that.

Comment: Is this still working?

Answer (score 9):

This not the best way to manage session in react you can use web tokens to encrypt your data that you want save,you can use various number of services available a popular one is [JSON web tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction/)(JWT) with web-tokens you can logout after some time if there no action from the client And after creating the token you can store it in your local storage for ease of access.

```
jwt.sign({user}, 'secretkey', { expiresIn: '30s' }, (err, token) => {
    res.json({
      token
  });
```

user object in here is the user data which you want to keep in the session

```
localStorage.setItem('session',JSON.stringify(token));
```

Comment: Storing tokens in localStorage is unsafe; localStorage isn't a secure store and if a bad actor grabs that token they can act on your behalf.

Comment: @Far_Eggs Why is it unsafe? So where should one save tokens? or what approach do you recommend?

Comment: Please stop recommending JWT for sessions. They're not meant for that. Read this for further info: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Comment: @PauloMadroñero In this case cookies are a better option when used correctly. With cookies you can, for example, a) prevent JS code to read/write the session cookie (think a 3rd party .js acting bad), b) limit usage to a specific domain to prevent hijacking (SecureSite), c) limit usage to https only to prevent bad actors from sniffing, others.

Answer (score 5):

To name a few we can use [redux-react-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-session) which is having good API for session management like, `initSessionService`, `refreshFromLocalStorage`, `checkAuth` and many other.  It also provide some advanced functionality like `Immutable JS`.

Alternatively we can leverage [react-web-session](https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-web-session) which provides options like `callback` and `timeout`.