# How can i have session management in React application?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js and have a need to maintain session of the application...lets say for 3 minutes.

Authentication is done by a third party (akamai) and i need to have the session management. Can someone guide me on this? Any github code/video? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would not recommend you manage sessions on the front-end as it's easy to hack.

With JWT (JSON Web Tokens) you create a token on your backend and your front-end just requests the latest token. Inside that token will be info on whether that session is still active (you'd control what is returned).

Find a good JWT guide set it up, then from React you make a simple fetch command to get the JWT and then parse it and boot the user as necessary.

There was a similar question to yours asked earlier in the year, please see below:

[What is the best way to manage a user's session in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420531/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-a-users-session-in-react)