# How to stay logged in when you're redirected from other pages?

Tags: reactjs

I am developing an app with ReactJs, the basic is done but now I have a problem. My app consists of 2 screens, one is called Login and the other is called Home. It's sort of a minigame linked to other pages. So if I have logged in on other pages, and then supposedly I click a button to redirect to my app, I want it to check the authentication before rendering, if the user is valid then it goes straight to Home, if not then the Login is required. Due to security reasons, I can't share any code, I just want to know what's the approach to this situation. Many thanks.

Comment: How are the "pages" wired up? Are you using e.g. react-router?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to manage a user's session in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42420531/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-a-users-session-in-react)

Comment: @AKX Yes, I am.

Comment: Okay. Then you'll need some global state to store the session in (zustand, react context, ...), and then the easiest might be to simply set up the router's routes so everything redirects to login if there are no credentials yet. Without being able to see code, that's pretty much the advice anyone can give.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to work from there